# Rotate GameObject on z degrees around the y axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject that tilts x degrees aound the z axis and z degrees around the x axis. I managed to do that using the following code

```
public float xtilt, ztilt, ytilt;

//These virables are public float values for how much tilt or rotation I want. 
//xtilt for how much rotation when moving on the x axis. 
//ztilt for how much rotation when moving on the z axis. 
//ytilt for how much rotation when moving on the y axis.

void FixedUpdate()
{
  Rigidbody rb;
  rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rb.velocity.z * ztilt, 0.0f, rb.velocity.x * -xtilt);
}
```

the code above gives me te following

- When moving around the z axis GameObject rotates x degrees.
- When moving around the x axis GameObject rotates z degrees.

**Objectives:**

I want to add : rotating or tilt the gameobject x degrees around the y axis.

So it will be like this:

- When moving around the y axis GameObject rotates x degrees.

I tried to go around the code to achieve this but with no luck.

any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `ztilt * rb.velocity.z = z degrees`.

If you wanted to rotate the object around the Y axis using zdegrees, shouldn't that supplant the Y parameter? Like so:

```
rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, rb.velocity.z * ztilt, 0f);
```

From the unity docs, the declaration for the euler function is:

```
public static Quaternion Euler(float x, float y, float z);
```

Comment: your first code will just rotate it y degrees around the z axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you want z degrees, then use the variable that contains the z value:

replace

```
rb.velocity.y * ytilt
```

by

```
rb.velocity.y * ztilt
```

Comment: the variables ztilt and ytilt are just values I set for how much tilt I want.

so it will just tilt or rotate y degrees with the value of ztilt

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand properly... To me, it seems you want to rotate angleX around x, angleZ around y, angleZ aroundZ, correct? if yes, `rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(angleX, angleZ, angleZ);` should do it. Didn't you just mistake y for z?

Comment: Moving aroundX rotates Zdegrees (angleZ), moving aroundZ rotates Xdegrees(angleX), moving aroundY rotates Xdegrees(angleX). that what should happen. For me this code works exactly as I want except when moving the GameObject around the Y axis `rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rb.velocity.z * ztilt, 0.0f, rb.velocity.x * -xtilt);`

Comment: I tried to play around this code `rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(angleX, angleZ, angleZ);` but with no luck. based on the documentation describing the code as this: "**Returns a rotation that rotates z degrees around the z axis, x degrees around the x axis, and y degrees around the y axis (in that order)**"

Comment: I feel like you misunderstood the doc. the arguments should start with the angle you want around the x axis, then y, then z. your code should look like Quaternion.Euler(x, y, z). Why are you using the z variable as the first argument? The sentence you put in bold means that Unity will apply your arguments starting with z, but it still has to be the third argument... Have you tried rotating just around one axis? Do you understand that rotating around x, then around y is not the same as rotating around y, then x?

Comment: yea, I know that the order is (x,y,z) that's why I am using `rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rb.velocity.z * ztilt, 0.0f, rb.velocity.x * -xtilt);` so I can have (X degrees around Z axis, 0.0f, z degrees around X axis). the order (x,y,z) is the order for rotation.

Comment: Sorry, I still have trouble understanding you... The way you name variables is not clear (what call it xTilt if this variable is related to Z rotation?). Also, I read your question again and still dont understand: you say you want to "tilt the gameobject z degrees around the y axis.", but your example code obviously rotates around y using the yTilt value... so of course it is wrong. Maybe try to edit your question with more info about what you want to achieve, what your variables contain and what result you currently get

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear from the beginning. I edited my Question explaining the use of the float virables. I use the virable with the relation to the axis not the rotation. I also posted the code for what works for me so far.